# How does the event get passed to the function without passing it through parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dom-events

I am new to React (though I think this could be a JS issue) and I am following a tutorial but I am not sure how 'e', which represents the `onChange` event, gets passed to the function. In Javascript, I think I would usually write something like `onchange="updateSearch(event);"` to pass the event. Here is the code:

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState(''); //state

const updateSearch = (e) => {   //here the onChange event is passed through
  setSearch(e.target.value);
  console.log(search);
}

return(
<input className="search-bar" type="text" value={search} onChange={updateSearch}/>
);
```

Comment: This is not something which happens only in react. This is how event listeners in javascript works. Whenever an event listener is added, you don't need to pass the event explicitly.

Comment: @rishabh0211 Where is the event listener added? Do you mean that onChange will pass the event object to whatever its value?

Comment: Yes. onChange is an event handler which returns a Synthetic Event object as the argument.
JavaScript allows us to listen to an input’s change in value by providing the attribute `onchange`. React’s version of the onchange event handler is the same, but camel-cased.

Answer (score 0):

The target event property returns the element that triggered the event and retrieves the value that's associated with it.

So value={search} is what is passed to setSearch(e.target.value)

Comment: Yes I was moreso confused with how the 'event' itself is passed to the function. How does my updateSearch function know what "e" is? Since I did not pass it in the input tag.